# Two-dimensional array as parameter of web-service method

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, asmx

I have created a web-service (ASMX) and added web method with two-dimensional array as input parameter.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public int myMethod(int[,] my_array)
    {
        return my_array[0,0];
    }
```

It is compiled succesfully. But when I try to add reference to this service from Silverlight project I get an error. Of course, I can change `int[,]` to `int[][]` and it will work. But how can I declare multidimensional array as a parameter of a Web service method without using this trick?